# How to group by column and drop or separate values in pandas?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns.

I want to group the dataframe by column 3 and it works, but my problem is in the display of the values of the other columns.

For row one, the values will always be the same, but instead of displaying the same value twice for that row in the output, I want to display it only once, so basically drop the duplicate.

For row two, I want to separate the values by a comma.

The grouping by works fine but I just can't seem to find out how to alter the output of the other two rows.

What works just fine for the grouping is

```
df_2 = df.groupby(['Postcode']).sum()
```

but the result of course doesn't drop the duplicate values in row 1 and doesn't comma separate the values in row 2.

Sorry for this question, it's probably not that hard but I really can't get my head around it so far.

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and `join`:

```
df = df.groupby('col3').agg({'col1':'first', 'col2':','.join})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this but then I end up with two columns instead of 3 when I check the shape somehow. :o

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I used your function and added as_index=False . Thanks a lot! :)